# TLS handshake with custom CA using wildcard egress

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio

I’m trying to setup istio (v1.7.3) on AKS (v1.16.13) in a way that for all HTTPS requests within my domain, the TLS handshake is performed transparently by egress gateway.

I ended up with something like this (abc.mydomain.com is an external URL so that’s why I created a ServiceEntry for it):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*.mydomain.com"
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-for-mydomain
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
    - name: mydomain
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      caCertificates: /etc/istio/mydomain-ca-certs/mydomain.crt
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-mydomain-through-egress-gateway
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*.mydomain.com"
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-egressgateway
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - "*.mydomain.com"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: mydomain
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - "*.mydomain.com"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: abc.mydomain.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: www-mydomain
spec:
  hosts:
  - abc.mydomain.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
```

I have mounted my certificate in the egress gateway and verified with: `kubectl exec -n istio-system “$(kubectl -n istio-system get pods -l istio=egressgateway -o jsonpath=’{.items[0].metadata.name}’)” – ls -al /etc/istio/mydomain-ca-certs`

I’m getting the following when invoking `curl -vvI https://abc.mydomain.com` from one of the pods running in another namespace:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to abc.mydomain.com:443
```

I’ve also tried what’s described here (Trust custom Root CA on Egress Gateway) but I’m getting the error as above.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**UPDATE1**

Here is an output of `istioctl proxy-status` (egress rds is *STALE*):

```
istio-egressgateway-695dc4fc7c-p5p42.istio-system               SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     STALE      istiod-5c6b7b5b8f-csggg     1.7.3                       41d
istio-ingressgateway-5689f7c67-j54m7.istio-system               SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     istiod-5c6b7b5b8f-csggg     1.7.3                       118d
```

Output of `curl -vvI https://abc.mydomain.com`:

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55ce54104f50)
*   Trying 10.223.24.254...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55ce54104f50)
* Connected to abc.mydomain.com (10.223.24.254) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to abc.mydomain.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to abc.mydomain.com:443
```

Output of `openssl s_client -connect abc.mydomain.com:443`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 328 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Any useful information from `curl -vvI` or `openssl`?

Comment: Do you have correct [port name](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/) in your service? I see you tried [that](https://discuss.istio.io/t/trust-custom-root-ca-on-egress-gateway/3063), but have you seen this [comment](https://discuss.istio.io/t/trust-custom-root-ca-on-egress-gateway/3063/3?)? Could you try to add `exportTo: '.'` in your destination rule as mentioned [here](https://discuss.istio.io/t/trust-custom-root-ca-on-egress-gateway/3063/8?)?

Comment: See UPDATE1 for detailed outputs. Jakub - after adding `exportTo: ['.']` in DestinationRule, nothing has changed in the outputs of curl and opennsl.